# How do I add two arraylists with an uneven amount of elements

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to get the sum of two array lists elements with a different amount of elements in each one is a method. So far, I have been able to get the elements to add, but when the results print, it leaves out numbers because the array lists have different elements. Let's say array list a has 5 elements and array list b has 3 elements. The missing amounts in the array are supposed to be 0. So if `a` has `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}` and `b` has `{2, 3, 1}`. The result should be `{3, 5, 4, 4, 5}`.

```
 public static ArrayList<Integer> sum(ArrayList<Integer> a, ArrayList<Integer> b)
  {
    ArrayList <Integer> result = new ArrayList <Integer> ();
    
     for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
       result.add(a.get(i) + b.get(i));
     }
     return result;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take two lists add each elements one by one and store there **sum** in **new list** if there is no more element in any of the list take the remaining elements from the **larger list** and **append** at the end of the **new list**.

```
import java.util.*;

public class MainSum{
    public static void main(String ... $){
        var out = System.out;
        List<Integer> a = new ArrayList<>(List.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
        List<Integer> b = new ArrayList<>(List.of(2, 3, 1));

        List<Integer> result = MainSum.sum(a, b);

        out.println(result);
    }
    public static List<Integer> sum(List<Integer> a, List<Integer> b){
        List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int index =0 ;index<a.size() && index< b.size();index++)
            result.add(a.get(index) + b.get(index));
        if( a.size() != b.size())
            result.addAll(a.size()>b.size()?a.subList(b.size(), a.size()):b.subList(a.size(), b.size()));
           return result;
    }
}
```

## Output:

```
[3, 5, 4, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that you have 2 arrays in different sizes, so you should take it into consideration and your loop can't be always on `a` size, since it might be bigger than `b` size and then you try to access elements that aren't exist.
Something you can do is to loop over elements which are exist in both arrays, and then complete the rest. Suggestion:

```
  public static ArrayList<Integer> sum(ArrayList<Integer> a, ArrayList<Integer> b) {
    ArrayList result = new ArrayList();
    int aSize = a.size();
    int bSize = b.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(aSize, bSize); i++) { // Loop over elements that exist in both arrays
      result.add(a.get(i) + b.get(i));
    }

    if (aSize > bSize) { // Complete missing from a
      for (int i = aSize - bSize + 1; i < aSize; i++) {
        result.add(a.get(i));
      }
    } else if (bSize > aSize) { // Complete missing from b
      for (int i = bSize - aSize + 1; i < bSize; i++) {
        result.add(b.get(i));
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure to iterate to the higher index, and make sure you don't run into a problem with a non existing index.

```
BiFunction<ArrayList<Integer>, Integer, Integer> getSafe =
   (l, i ) -> i < l.size() ? l.get(i) : 0;
for (int i = 0; i < Math.max(list1.size(), list2.size(); i++) {
  result.add(getSafe.apply(list1) + getSafe.apply(list1));
}
```

Or with an `Iterator` if you want to overengineer

```
Iterator<Integer> bothIterator = new Iterator<>() {
 Iterator<Integer> it1 = list1.iterator();
 Iterator<Integer> it2 = list2.iterator();
 public boolean hasNext() {
  return it1.hasNext() || it2.hasNext();
 }
 public Integer next() {
  int result = it1.hasNext() ? it1.next();
  result += it2.hasNext() ? it2.next() : 0;
  return result;
 }
}
int result = 0;
while (bothIterator.hasNext()) {
 result += bothIterator.next();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach can be based on customizing each list return values.

```
public class TestArrSum {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        List<Integer> a = List.of(1,2,3,4,5); 
        List<Integer> b = List.of(2,3,1);
        List<Integer> result = sum(a,b);
        result.forEach(System.out::println);

    }
    public static List<Integer> sum(List<Integer> a, List<Integer> b)
    {
         List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
         for(int i=0;i<a.size() || i<b.size();i++)
         {
             result.add(getValue(a,i)+getValue(b,i));
         }
         
         return result;
    }
    
    public static int getValue(List<Integer> l,int i)
    {
        try
        {
            return l.get(i);
        }
        catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Note: One advantage can be in terms of verbosity in case if need that method signature to contain more lists to be sum.

The same result can be obtained also with an intermediary data structure which latter will be transformed to List.

```
static class MyMap extends HashMap<Integer,Integer>
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    MyMap()
    {
        super();
    }

    public void putKV(Integer key,Integer value)
    {
        Integer old = this.get(key);
        if(old==null)
        {
            this.put(key, value);
        }
        else
        {
            this.put(key, old+value);
        }
        System.out.println(key+":"+value+":"+this.get(key));
        
    }
    public List<Integer> toList()
    {
        List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int i=0; i<this.size();i++)
        {
            l.add(this.get(i));
        }
        return l;
    }
}
```

Can be used as:

```
MyMap m = new MyMap();
for(int i=0;i<a.size();i++)
{
    m.putKV(i, a.get(i));
}
for(int i=0;i<b.size();i++)
{
    
    m.putKV(i, b.get(i));
}

List<Integer> resultM = m.toList();
resultM.forEach(k->System.out.println(k));
```